# rubyzip/zippy - extract in place

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, zip, rubyzip

Simple I think but can't seem to find something that works. Using either rubyzip or zippy.

I need to extract "path/to/my/file.zip to "path/to/my/file"

Documentation is quite slim for either gems.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just call the **gunzip** process?

```
system("gunzip -S '.zip' file.jpeg.zip")
```

No need to use/install any gem.

Comment: But he need to use proper system and depend on extrnal app.

Comment: It is very unlikely that someone is running a Rails app in a system that doesn't have **gunzip** (and that would be Windows).

Comment: Better option is to use Delayed Job and any Zip lib for Ruby.

Comment: I ended up using delayed_job and a zip library for ruby as per Hauleth. Can't mark it as the answer since its a comment.